# how to grep list.txt to print files whose names partly match the list

Tags: unix, grep

I have a list of files in my directory

[image]

I want to select those whose names partly include the names in the list.txt

```
monCan3F9-B-G1785-Map20
monCan3F9-B-G2556-Map3
monCan3F9-B-G2798-Map3
monCan3F9-B-G2800-Map5
```

when typing `grep -E -f list.txt` nothing happens.
I can do it one by one, e.g. `grep| *monCan3F9-B-G1785-Map20*` , but how should I print all the files' names at once?

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 | grep -F -f list.txt
```

N.B. The first option flag is the numeric digit one (to force output to be one entry per line), not the lowercase letter "ell" (for long format).

The -F flag is probably not needed (it isn't needed to cater for the hyphens, for example), but might be safest if the partial file names in your file will always be fixed strings.

Comment: still doesn't print them :/ neither with -F nor without

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: And which version of `grep`? (use `grep --version` to find out)

Comment: bash shell and grep (GNU grep) 2.25